# div width transition with flex

Tags: css-transitions, flexbox

Based on the following example:

```
<div style="display: flex" ng-mouseenter="temp = true" ng-mouseleave="temp = false">
    <div style="border: 1px solid; width: 100%; transition: 1s width">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
    <div ng-show="temp" style="width: 50px">bbb</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to animate the first div when the second one is removed. I've searched and tried different solutions but with no luck. The first div width is adapting with no animation. Maybe it could depend by the fact that the first div width is always set to 100%.

Any help?

Comment: Here's a plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/uk6fCeuteZmEM20OjM1a?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class on the `div` not being removed, at the time the other one is removed. This class will transition the width of the existing `div` to 100%. It's not perfect, but might give you some ideas.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button'),
    firstDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.firstDiv'),
    lastDiv = document.querySelector('.lastDiv');

button.addEventListener('click', removeLastDiv);

function removeLastDiv() {
  firstDiv[0].classList.add('grow');
  document.querySelector('.parent').removeChild(lastDiv);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.parent div {
  width: 50%;
  transition: 1s;
}

.parent .firstDiv.grow {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Boring button styles — ignore */
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: gray;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="firstDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima temporibus recusandae numquam, iste nemo! Obcaecati corrupti quibusdam tempora officia, nostrum atque aliquam culpa, facilis odit fugiat iure et quas dolorum</div>
  <div class="lastDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore architecto recusandae dolore, maiores, tempora aut fugiat placeat odit dignissimos eaque libero quam expedita quos possimus nulla itaque veniam at dolor.</div>
</div>

<button>Remove last div</button>
```